# Installing Pow for Rails 4 hangs on MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-4, macos-sierra, rack-pow, launchctl

I have been trying to install pow (for Rails) on MacOS Sierra, but it gets hung after giving the password asked for root privilegies.

```
$ curl get.pow.cx | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9039  100  9039    0     0  28008      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 30029
*** Installing Pow 0.5.0...
*** Installing local configuration files...
/Users/robertolimon/Library/LaunchAgents/cx.pow.powd.plist
*** Installing system configuration files as root...
Password:
```

According to the current documentation, it should show the following lines after giving password:

```
/etc/resolver/dev
/Library/LaunchDaemons/cx.pow.firewall.plist
*** Starting the Pow server...
*** Performing self-test...
*** Installed
```

So, I canceled it after more than 35 minutes waiting and I found it does not create the file /Library/LaunchDaemons/cx.pow.firewall.plist referenced in the Pow installer script:

```
  if [ $NEEDS_ROOT -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "*** Installing system configuration files as root..."
    sudo "$NODE_BIN" "$POW_BIN" --install-system

    if [ "$MAC_OS_MINOR_VERSION" -ge 10 ]; then
      sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/cx.pow.firewall.plist 2>/dev/null
      sudo launchctl enable system/cx.pow.firewall 2>/dev/null
      sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/cx.pow.firewall 2>/dev/null
    else
      sudo launchctl load -Fw /Library/LaunchDaemons/cx.pow.firewall.plist 2>/dev/null
    fi
  fi
```

Any idea to solve this problem?
How or where can I get this file?

Thanks

---

**Dec 30 '16 at 20:32**

Still working on this issue, I found the script gets stuck on the following line:

```
sudo "$NODE_BIN" "$POW_BIN" --install-system
```

Before the block of code I mentioned on my first comment.

The value of those variables are:

```
POW_ROOT="$HOME/Library/Application Support/Pow"
NODE_BIN="$POW_ROOT/Current/bin/node"
POW_BIN="$POW_ROOT/Current/bin/pow"
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks

---

**Dec 30 '16 at 23:58**

I apply the instructions described in the following link:

http://blog.radi.ws/post/123989557948/running-pow-050-on-os-x-el-capitan-1011-beta

But still is not working.

---

**Feb 20 '18 at 09:40**

I solved installing a fresh macOS Sierra on my Mac.

Comment: Did you consider to use `puma-dev` instead `pow`? https://github.com/puma/puma-dev

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try it.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem and fixed it by enabling the root user.

1. Choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups (or Accounts).
2. Click lock icon, then enter an administrator name and password.
3. Click Login Options.
4. Click Join (or Edit).
5. Click Open Directory Utility.
6. Click lock icon in the Directory Utility window, then enter an administrator name and password.
7. From the menu bar in Directory Utility:
   Choose Edit > Enable Root User, then enter the password that you want to use for the root user.

source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012